# MySQL Load Data Infile for a String

Tags: mysql

Here is my CSV File, namely, Example.csv and my Table name is Example-

```
"ePID,Title,Brand,Manufacture Part Number,SubType,Type,Category ID,Category Breadcrumb"
"74416490,Drive-Rite 231039 A/C Drive Belt Tensioner Pulley,Drive-Rite,231039,A/C Drive Belt Tensioner Pulley|Drive Belt Idler Pulley,Accessory Drive Belt System Components,38656,""eBay Motors:Parts & Accessories:Car & Truck Parts:Engines & Components:Belts, Pulleys & Brackets"""
```

My SQL Loading Command is-

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Example.csv REPLACE INTO TABLE `Example` CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I am getting all data into the first column.

Answer (score 0):

The data in file looks incorrect.

Due to the position of double quotes the entire line is being interpreted as one column. Either remove the double quotes or just enclose each column with double quotes.

Try with this :-

ePID,Title,Brand,Manufacture Part Number,SubType,Type,Category ID,Category, Breadcrumb
74416490,Drive-Rite 231039 A/C Drive Belt Tensioner Pulley,Drive-Rite,231039,A/C Drive Belt Tensioner Pulley|Drive Belt Idler Pulley,Accessory Drive Belt System Components,38656,eBay Motors:Parts & Accessories:Car & Truck Parts:Engines & Components:Belts, Pulleys & Brackets

Comment: Therefore, I have called this a string.

Comment: Point is that this is not a correct csv format. Let me know if you get the same results after removing the double quotes.

Comment: Can not remove double quote from both ends.

Comment: I found below solution on this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html                                                                                                                                    If you are running LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from the windows shell and you need to use OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"', you will have to do something like this in order to escape characters properly
mysql -u root -p -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '!file!' INTO TABLE !table! FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"^""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"